# Connect STM32F4 with smart card ISO7816

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, smart-card, iso7816

everybody. My task is to connect STM32F4 discovery Board with Smart Card ISO7816. I don't use interface ST8024CDR only hooked paid directly by the scheme specified in the image:
[image]

I tried to adapt the Cubex project to STM32F1xx-EVAL. ATR reception does not work. The oscilloscope shows that the I/O port from the map is something similar to a sawtooth signal, but more flat (on three different maps it is different). So I guess it's still an ATR.

The configuration of the UART and frequency:
[image]

```
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
 RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
 RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

 /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
 */
 __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
 __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG( PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);
 /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
 */
 RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
 RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
 RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
 RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
 RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
 RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
 RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 168;
 RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
 RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 4;
 if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
 {
   Error_Handler();
 }
 /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
 */
 RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                             |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
 RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
 RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
 RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
 RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

 if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK)
 {
   Error_Handler();
 }
}

static void MX_USART1_SMARTCARD_Init(void){
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */
    __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();
    /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */
    /* USART Clock set to 3,5 MHz (PCLK2 (84 MHz) / 24) */
    /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
    SmartCardHandle.Instance = USART1;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.BaudRate = 9408;    /* Starting baudrate = 3,5MHz / 372etu */
    SmartCardHandle.Init.WordLength = SMARTCARD_WORDLENGTH_9B;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.StopBits = SMARTCARD_STOPBITS_1_5;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.Parity = SMARTCARD_PARITY_EVEN;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.Mode = SMARTCARD_MODE_TX_RX;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.CLKPolarity = SMARTCARD_POLARITY_LOW;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.CLKPhase = SMARTCARD_PHASE_1EDGE;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.CLKLastBit = SMARTCARD_LASTBIT_DISABLE;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.Prescaler = 12;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.GuardTime = 16;
    SmartCardHandle.Init.NACKState = SMARTCARD_NACK_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_SMARTCARD_Init(&SmartCardHandle) != HAL_OK)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    __HAL_SMARTCARD_ENABLE(&SmartCardHandle);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */
    HAL_SMARTCARD_Init(&SmartCardHandle);
    SC_RESET(GPIO_PIN_SET);
    /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */
}

void HAL_SMARTCARD_MspInit(SMARTCARD_HandleTypeDef* hsmartcard)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
    if(hsmartcard->Instance==USART1)
    {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 0 */

    /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 0 */
        /* Peripheral clock enable */
        __HAL_RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

        __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
        /**USART1 GPIO Configuration    
        PA8     ------> USART1_CK
        PA9     ------> USART1_TX 
        */
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_OD;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
        GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF7_USART1;
        HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

        /* USART1 interrupt Init */
        HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 0, 0);
        HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_MspInit 1 */

    /* USER CODE END USART1_MspInit 1 */
    }

}
```

Trying to read directly:

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_Delay(500);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
convention=HAL_SMARTCARD_Receive(&SmartCardHandle, atr_buff, atr_size, 500);
HAL_Delay(12);
/* Insert delay of 20ms for signal stabilization */
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);
HAL_Delay(300);
```

PD15 - Reset.
I always get zeros. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, the problem is solved very simply. I used USART3 instead of USART1 and everything was considered successful.